# Make a polygon/circle shape blend into rest of google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Right now I have a circle being created by a maps.Polygon. I can set the strokeWeight: 0 and that removes the line around the polygon, can I blend it in so the point of demarcation between the circle and the rest of the map isn't a distinctive line. Ex. in picture below.

Here is my code for the polygon.

```
var $googlemap; //this code is above polygon code
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var outerbounds = [ // covers the (mercator projection) world
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 0),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 90),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(0, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180)];

// options for the polygon
var populationOptions = {
    //strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    //strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    //fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: $googlemap,
    paths: [outerbounds, drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(mapCoordinates.latitude, mapCoordinates.longitude), .1, -1)]
};
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Polygon(populationOptions);
$googlemap.fitBounds(bounds);


function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) {
var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles
var points = 32;

// find the raidus in lat/lon 
var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r);

var extp = new Array();
if (dir == 1) { var start = 0; var end = points + 1 } // one extra here makes sure we connect the ends
else { var start = points + 1; var end = 0 }
for (var i = start; (dir == 1 ? i < end : i > end) ; i = i + dir) {
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points / 2));
    ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
    ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
    extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey));
    bounds.extend(extp[extp.length - 1]);
}
return extp;
}
```

Here is what my map currently looks like.

[image]

Here is what I want it to look like.
I want the circle to blend to the rest of the map.

[image]

Comment: Not possible with a documented API method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-existing library (Even third party) or API that would help you achieve this task. You can try something with the [Google Maps Styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyler). You have two options:

- You need to edit the gamma and lightness styles. This is not a transparency effect, which means it will not allow to see any element that would be behind the map but it should achieve the fade out effect that looks similar to your example where you want to achieve.
- The lightness defaults parameter at 0 so you will want to decrease it to a negative number if that is your aim. Decreasing the saturation might give more of the effect you want.

You can try this out in the close proximity of your maker and may work too.

Hope that Helps!!

Answer (score -1):

In theory, if you're not dealing with a large number of markers, you could lay down a large number of low-opacity circles with the same center and varying radii.